# How to fill RadGrid NestedViewTemplate from code behind?

Tags: vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Got a situation when I need to move RadGrid from front page to code.

It used to look like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid id="rgBooks" runat="server"
    Height="300px"
    Skin="Office2007"     
    EnableViewState="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <MasterTableView 
            EditMode="inplace"
            TableLayout="auto" 
            ClientDataKeyNames="BookID, BookName, Created, Modified, BookTypeName, BookTypeID"
            NoMasterRecordsText="No available books." >
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" />
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Arial" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True" BackColor="White"/>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" Width="99%" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
            <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Arial" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True" BackColor="White"/>  
            <NestedViewTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            BookType Type:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBookTypes" AutoPostBack="true" /> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    ....
                    ....

            </NestedViewTemplate>
            <columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Book Name" HeaderStyle-Width="33%" ItemStyle-Width="33%" UniqueName="BookName" DataField="BookName" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Created" HeaderStyle-Width="33%" ItemStyle-Width="33%" UniqueName="Created" DataField="Created" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Modified" HeaderStyle-Width="33%" ItemStyle-Width="33%" UniqueName="Modified" DataField="Modified" />
            </columns>

            ....
            ....

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And recreating this in code looks like this:

```
Dim rgBooks As New RadGrid : With rgBooks
   .ID = "rgBooks"
   .Height = New Unit(300, UnitType.Pixel)
   .Skin = "Office2007"

   ....
   ....       

End With

Me.placeHolder.Controls.Add(rgBooks)
```

It works fine EXCEPT for `<NestedViewTemplate>`. Didn't found a way to send there my values (table), and literally no documentation about how to do it.
As I understand, it supposed to look like `rgBooks.MasterTableView.NestedViewTemplate.InstantiateIn(  and here my data )` but each attempt to sent there something ended with failure, and with exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Also tried to sent  as LiteralControl.

```
rgBooks.MasterTableView.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<NestedViewTemplate>"))
rgBooks.MasterTableView.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<table>"))
rgBooks.MasterTableView.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<tr>"))
....
....
```

Didn't worked out.

How I suppose to fill `NestedViewTemplate` in code correctly (it is `ITemplate` by the way)?

Comment: "fill"  ? Do you mean `bind`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English, but if it is understandable, I'm glad :) Not sure, maybe bind will be a correct word

Comment: Maybe this help you : https://www.telerik.com/forums/bind-nestedviewtemplate-from-code-behind

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately example is very bad there. It binds data from code befind, but I need literally create a whole NestedViewTemplate from code behind

Comment: There are more examples and information about it, please search for bind RadGrid NestedViewTemplate........    good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out how it supposed to work.

A custom class required

```
Public Class NestedTemplate
    Implements ITemplate

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn

        container.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<table>"))
        container.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<tr>"))

        ....
        ....

        container.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</table>"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then just

```
rgBooks.MasterTableView.NestedViewTemplate = new NestedTemplate
```

Oh boy, how much time I wasted on this thing...